# Apache and Passenger performance on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, amazon-web-services, passenger

I am seeing a strange issue on AWS and I was hoping to see if anyone had any insight into what it might be?

Setup:
t2.medium instance utilising 3 EBS GP2 volumes in a raid0 group
elasticache (memcached)
Local mysql configured to run from the raid group
Ubuntu 14.04
Apache 2.4.7
Passenger 5.1.7
Logs are sent to papertrail and not written to local disc

The test:

The test is run from jmeter on a t2.micro instance in AWS which visits the home page, logs in, views a profile page, then logs back out. There are DB queries made at the Login and Profile View, but mysql doesn't appear to be the bottle neck.

Test configuration 1:
mpm_event.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
StartServers        10
MinSpareThreads     75
MaxSpareThreads     250
ThreadLimit     128
ThreadsPerChild     32
MaxRequestWorkers   1984
ServerLimit     800
MaxConnectionsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

And the passenger.conf looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby
PassengerMaxPoolSize 30
PassengerPoolIdleTime 150
PassengerPreStart *** points to host in /etc/hosts ***
PassengerMaxRequestQueueSize 500
</IfModule>
```

So the above config results in no errors (in part by the increase in the RequestQueueSize) but responses are taking north of 90seconds(!) towards the end of the test.

Now, here's where things get weird, if I change the configuration of passenger to:

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby
PassengerMaxPoolSize 2
PassengerPoolIdleTime 150
PassengerPreStart *** points to host in /etc/hosts ***
PassengerMaxRequestQueueSize 500
</IfModule>
```

The response times are faster, bringing them down to 60seconds, which is still slow but much better.

What I see when monitoring (using htop, iotop, iftop, mytop, free -m and passenger-status) is the queue in passenger-status grows steadily from the start of the test, if there was a 100 queue limit as standard, it'd start serving 503 errors, but when the queue is increased the requests queue for large amounts of time.

Passenger-enterprise isn't really an option for me to use.

I'm doing something wrong here with the passenger config or with mpm right? This server should be able to handle 600+ connections and respond in 1.3s max (I've run the same tests on a server in Brightbox, and the performance is ridiculously good comparing)

I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Note:

I've ran through the calculations for memory usage for passenger, which should stand at 35, I used 30 to not completely max out RAM due to not running swap, because it's even worse when it hits it.

Answer (score 0):

Passenger author here. This sounds like you are running into some bottleneck inside, or behind, the application. If your application cannot process requests fast enough, then it's normal that the Passenger request queue keeps growing until its limit. It is then also normal that the more you increase the queue, the slower your responses are towards the end of the queue.

That more processes makes things slower sounds like your processes are contending for a shared resource that only supports very low concurrency. That might be the database, but you already ruled that out. It might be a web service that you call. It might be a file lock. Without knowledge about your application, I cannot tell what the problem exactly is, but at the very least it does not seem like Passenger is the problem.

Comment: I'll add that profiling your webapp with [rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) and [flamegraphs](https://github.com/CamJN/flamegraph) gems is a great, and easy way to find these bottlenecks. (The flamegraphs gem I linked is my own fork which is easier to read & interpret).